# Caching asynchronous responses in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

How might I save the response of a completion handler in a static variable? In the sample code

```
GTLQueryTictactoe *query = [GTLQueryTictactoe queryForScoresList];
[service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLTictactoeScores *object, NSError *error) {
  NSArray *items = [object items];
  // Do something with items.
}];
```

Where it says `// Do something with items` I want to save the `items` in a static variable
so that anyone can call `getMyItems` to get the items. How might I do that? And I do mean static variable in the objective-c sense where the values are remembered.

Image the snippet above is inside class `Dog`. And class `Paper` will need to use the items so that `getMyItems` will be called from inside class `Paper`. I am hoping not to have to save the items in Core Data.

Now I am thinking that my solution involves declaring `static NSArray *items` outside of the block. But then how will some other method access it? Is that even a good solution?

And would the following "solution" cause a memory leak because I am calling `self` inside the block?

```
@implementation Dog

static NSArray *items;

-(void) callToServer
{
GTLQueryTictactoe *query = [GTLQueryTictactoe queryForScoresList];
    [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLTictactoeScores *object, NSError *error) {
      self.items = [object items];
    }];
}


-(NSArray *) getMyItems
{
  return items;
}
@end
```

Comment: I don't think this implementation is going to work very well. What happens if someone runs callToServer and then immediately calls getMyItems?

Comment: Is your goal to cache the response so you don't need to wait as long for the data in the future? Even if the data might be cached, you shouldn't assume it is so your "getter" method needs to be asynchronous using callback blocks.

Comment: @CrimsonChris `callToServer` will include an NSNotification. I leave it out for simplicity. Assuming that sending the data as `userInfo` is not sufficient, I was hoping to be able to cache the data so that later calls to `getMyItems` would work. So really don't worry about race conditions. How do I cache with a static variable?

Comment: Seems like a bad design. Blocks are simpler and less bug prone than notifications. Consider combining your two methods into one. Your signature could be something like `getDataWithCallback:` and would either load from the server or use a cached response if available.

Comment: @CrimsonChris what you said just flew over my head. I don't quite know how to do that. Do you mind showing a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this solution is in no way thread safe. Use it as a starting point for a more flexible solution.

### MyLoader.h

```
typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id object);

@interface MyLoader : NSObject
+ (void)loadItemsWithCallback:(CallbackBlock)callback; //callback takes an NSArray* of MyData*
+ (void)invalidateCache;
@end
```

### MyLoader.m

```
#import "MyLoader.h"

static NSArray *myCachedItems;

@implementation MyLoader

+ (void)loadItemsWithCallback:(CallbackBlock)callback {
    if (myCachedItems == nil) {
        [self executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLTictactoeScores *object, NSError *error) {
            myCachedItems = [object items];
            if (callback) callback(myCachedItems);
        }];
    } else {
        if (callback) callback(myCachedItems);
    }
}

+ (void)invalidateCache {
    myCachedItems = nil;
}

@end
```

### Using MyLoader

```
[MyLoader loadItemsWithCallback:^(NSArray *items) {
    /* When this callback executes, we have either just received data from the server
     * or cached data depending on if this request has been run already */
    self.items = items;
    [self reloadData]; //if this is for a UITableView
}];
```